# how can we switch on landscape mode from portrait on mac os in android

Tags: android

How can we switch on landscape mode from portrait on Mac OS in andriod?

I already tried with <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mac you may need to press <kbd>CMD</kbd> key as well, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>.

**Edited:**

You need to press <kbd>FN</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>.